# Way to implement English localization by Yup-locals

Tags: vue-i18n

****Does any of you have any idea how can I implement English localization option by yup-locales npm package?****
AS I saw this packages provide list of the languages(
ar,
de,
es,
fr,
he,
it,
nb,
nl,
pt,
tr
) but didn't find any English language option. Just started to work before 1 month with Vue framework, so still don't know so much about Vue ecosystem. I will wait for your valuable answer.

Thanks in advance!!!

npm package:
[yup-locales-link](https://github.com/loicmahieu/yup-locales#readme)

**Note:** My website in German language and previous developer added yup-locales for localization only for German language.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My question was about is it possible to integrate English and German language translation and localization options by vue-i18n ,yup-locales? I didn't understand fully yet what is yup-locales npm package used for. Is this library used for language dictionary purpose and how to use it? My previous developer used it. My website is based on vue composition api,typescript. If anybody have idea about yup-locales npm packages ,please share your experience.